# How to get the longest shortest path in my graph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm trying to get all longest shortest paths on my graph and i did write this code:

```
    for source in g.nodes:
      for dist in g.nodes:
        if source!=dist:
          distination=len(nx.shortest_path(g,source,dist))
          if distination>3:
            print(source,dist,distination)
```

the out put of this code is like this

```
    0 1 7
    0 2 7
    0 3 7
    0 4 6
    0 5 6
    0 6 5
    0 7 4
    0 8 7
    0 9 6
    0 10 7
    0 11 8
    0 12 5
    0 13 7
    0 14 8
    0 15 5
    0 16 8
    0 18 5
    0 19 6
    0 20 6
    0 21 6
    0 22 8
    0 23 5
    0 26 7
    0 27 8
    0 28 5
    0 29 8
    0 30 4
    0 31 8
```

it gave me the the required results but, is there is more professionals way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length` wich will give you all the shortest path for each node and then you can loop with it

```
ppp=nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(g)
for i in ppp:
  node=max(i[1], key=i[1].get)
  print(i[0],node,len(nx.shortest_path(g,i[0],node)))
```